# File read not finding file

Tags: java

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/User1/Documents/ServerSettings.dat"));
```

The code above cannot find the file specified. It definitely exists at the location specified.

The error given is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User1\Documents\ServerSettings.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Did you mistype "new file" in the q? It should read "new File" (capital F).
Please paste the exception thrown (tell us what the error message you got is).

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you run it? Is it "`FileNotFoundException`" or "`Count not resolve file`"? The two are very, very different! :)

Comment: On your windows system, are file extensions hidden? If they are, and you wrote a text file then renamed it, windows might have named your file "ServerSettings.dat.txt" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code isn't compiling it's because you have file with a lowercase 'f' in `new file` part of the code. If this is right in your code and your problem is at runtime try

`System.out.println( "exists? " + new File("C:/Users/User1/Documents/ServerSettings.dat").exists() );`

to see if the file really does exist
Or copy and paste the file path to windows explorer.

Comment: When I paste into Windows Explorer it finds it, however, when I execute the code you said it returns false.

Comment: @Jon it might be becasue the process does not have enough permissions to tell if the file exists?

Comment: How would I go about changing them? Or is that a Windows thing?

Comment: @Jon Well, you could try changing the permissions on the file/dir or you could try running the Java app as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because you're trying to construct a `new file` instead of a `new File`? If so, that would likely result in a compile-time error unless you've got a custom class named `file` on your classpath.